# How to rotated left axis label in stack bar charts?

Tags: swift, charts

I am using Charts library. I want to rotate left axis label to 90 degrees. How can I do that? Please help me.

I am able to rotate `xAxis` label. This is how I rotate `xAxis`:

```
barChart.xAxis.labelPosition = XAxis.LabelPosition.topInside
barChart.xAxis.labelRotationAngle = kXAxisLabelRotationAngleForShareOfVoiceByDrugs
```

And for `leftAxis`:

```
barChart.leftAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(values:hotTopicsAndWeakSignalsModel.barChartDrugNames)
barChart.leftAxis.labelPosition = .outsideChartr
```

How can set rotation to `leftAxis`?

Answer (score 0):

To rotate the xAxis Label, you need to do this:

```
barChart.xAxis.labelRotationAngle = YOUR_ANGLE
```

like

```
barChart.xAxis.labelRotationAngle = 90.0
```